# Django model DateField attribute limit choices

Tags: python, django, django-models, datefield

**background:** So im trying to build a "Bill" model with the attributes Name (name of payee), Amount (how much $ to pay), and PayDate (when to pay the bill).

**What I am stuck on:** I'm having some hard time trying to limit the PayDate input from 1 (first of the month) to 31 (last day of the month (Depending on the month))

**This is my code for the model:**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Bill(models.Model) :
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200, editable=True, blank=False)
    Amount = models.DecimalField(editable=True, blank=False, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
    PayDate = models.IntegerField(
        blank=False, editable=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.Name} @ ${self.Amount} every {self.PayDate} of the month"
```

I would love to get your suggestions on how to set the PayDate attribute.

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research? I have a hard time believing that there is no information available on how to do this. Why store the date as an integer, and not using a proper date/time type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IntegerField`s have a `MinValueValidator` and a `MaxValueValidator`. Validatiors can be used like so:

```
PayDate = models.IntegerField(
        blank=False, editable=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(1),MaxValueValidator(31)])
```

If you want the maximum value to change depending on the month you will have to do that in your form as validations on the models are fixed

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `DateField` for storing the Pay date. By doing that, it will be always a valid date. By adding `auto_now_add=False`, you will also be able to edit the field.

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Bill(models.Model) :
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200, editable=True, blank=False)
    Amount = models.DecimalField(editable=True, blank=False, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
    PayDate = models.DateField(blank=False, auto_now_add=False)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.Name} @ ${self.Amount} every {self.PayDate} of the month"
```